# after installing Android studio installation this error is showing

Tags: android-studio

java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-28_r07.zip': Read timed out , response: 200 OK Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-28_r07.zip': Read timed out , response: 200 OK